# How do I get an input for the UV Map of the Normal Map node?

Tags: shader-nodes, normal-map

I have a Normal Map node inside a group. I can't know in advance what the name of the UV Map to use might be. How do I supply this to the node?

What I have:

[image: current state]

What I need:

[image: required state]

Comment: Hello ! I don't think you can. You may be able to get this functionality with a custom geometry node tree though, would that be satisfying or do you absolutely need a shader-only solution ?

Comment: I've never touched other node trees before, so...maybe? Something rather than nothing I guess.